# are there mechanisms, to disable file_get_contents() function working?

Tags: php

i use [file_get_contents function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to grab data from sites and store the data in database. it will be very inconvenient for me, if one day the script will start not working.

I know, that it can start not working, if they change the structure of site, but now i'm afraid, that maybe there are mechanisms to disable the working of this function, maybe from server?

i tried to find documentation about it, but can't get, so maybe you will help me?

Thanks

Comment: Are you on a shared host? If so i would check to 'terms of use'. If your traffic is in the boundaries of the terms then no worries. No (professional) shared host would ever change config without notfying clients.
If you want to be sure that no one is messing with the server conf, think of getting a VPS. With a VPS you can have "your own server", you'll admin and configure it yourself. I currently have a (dv) server at MediaTemple - just love it! Used to have my own server setup at home, but to much worries about uptime and hardware failure made me look for other options. Never looked back!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know, that it can start not working,
>   if they change the structure of site,
>   but now i'm afraid, that maybe there
>   are mechanisms to disable the working
>   of this function, maybe from server?

Yes, it can be disabled from php.ini with [`allow_url_fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) option. You have other options such as [**CURL extension**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) too.

Note also that you will need to have **openssl** extension turned on from php.ini if you are going to use the `file_get_contents` function to read from a secure protocol.

So in case `file_get_contents` is/gets disabled, you can go for **[CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)** extension.

Comment: And if you don't want to rely on curl, you can go the manual route with fsockopen. This function is in the core of PHP. There's also the http pecl extension.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to disable certain functions using [*disable_function*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions). Furthermore the support of URLs with [filesystem functions](http://php.net/ref.filesystem) like `file_get_contents` can be disabled with [*allow_url_fopen*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen). So chances are that `file_get_contents` might not work as expected one day.

Comment: hmmm, too bad:/ and what can i do in this case, to be abble to get the data?

Comment: @Syom: There are special functions for requesting URLs like http://php.net/book.curl

Comment: @Syom: Oh, you could also use a stream context with `file_get_contents` (see *context* parameter).

Comment: @Artefacto: You can create a context as a wrapper. See http://php.net/stream_context_create for an example of use.

Comment: @Gumbo What I didn't understand was the relevance to the question, but I guess you're just saying how he could things he would otherwise need curl for.

Comment: @Artefacto: Yes, using a stream context is just an alternative to when *allow\_url\_fopen* or `file_get_contents` is disabled.

Comment: @Gumbo OK, now I'm not following. The stream context just parameterizes the stream that's about to be opened, as far as I know it doesn't allow allow_url_fopen to be circumvented.

Comment: @Artefacto: Ah, you’re right. A stream context won’t help if *allow\_url\_fopen* is disabled.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two PHP configuration directives that can break your script :

- If [**`allow_url_fopen`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) is disabled, then, `file_get_contents()` will not be able to fetch files that are not on the local disk

  - i.e. it will not be able to load remote pages via HTTP.
  - Note : I've seen that option disabled quite a few times
- And, of course, with [**`disable_functions`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions), any PHP function can be disabled.

Chances are pretty low that `file_get_contents()` itself will ever get disabled...

But remote-file loading... Well, it might be wise to add an alternative loading mecanism to your script, that would use [**curl**](https://www.php.net/curl) in case `allow_url_fopen` is disabled.