# Unable to execute file_get_contents in component

Tags: joomla, file-get-contents

I am trying to insert the data from file into database using file_get_contents through jobline component. But i am unable to execute the function inside the component when i had written the code outside the joomla it is working fine below is the working code. Can anyone suggest me what should i do?

Comment: $data = $dbLink->real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']));

Comment: Can you post more of your code? How do you initiate the Joomla DB object? Do you not want to use the JFile::read class? See here http://docs.joomla.org/API15:JFile/read

Comment: This might also be useful to you http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_the_filesystem_package

Answer (score 0):

Go on [are there mechanisms, to disable file_get_contents() function working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271333/are-there-mechanisms-to-disable-file-get-contents-function-working)